# How to filter array by array of dynamic objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

i have a huge collection of data 700+ items in, and i want to filter by dynamic array of objects, lets say that user has typed `ode` and my script should search on every filter without i do something like `filter.code == store.code`

```
const hugeData = [{name:"store 1",code : "code 1", available : false},{name : "store 2",code : "simple_code",available : true},{name : "sto 3",code : "has no cde",available : true}...]

const filters = [{ code : "ode", name : "re" }]
```

the result that im expecting is

```
// output
[{name : "store 1", code : "code 1", available : false},{name : "store 2",code : "simple_code",available : true}]
```

i resolved this doing the following with `lodash`, but function is very slow, and code is poor, is there any other way that i can do this works?

```
const results = []
_.map(hugeData, store => {
    _.map(filters, tag => {
        Object.keys(tag).map(tagOb => {
          if (store[tagOb] && store[tagOb].includes(tag[tagOb])) {
             results.push(store);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: couldn't `filters` just be a single object of key value pairs? why would it need to be in an array?

Comment: @Anthony yes, i can modify it, but if its a simple object, how that should work?

Comment: does multiple filters mean they all have to match?

Comment: what is `ode` ?

Comment: @Anthony not all have to match, with only one that matches, result should appear

Comment: @Addis is `code` minus `c`, just for find results that matches with that `word` on any of the attributes of the store

Comment: in your example, store 3 should match then, on name as it has `re` in it too

Comment: @Anthony i updated that code, please reload the page to see it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `some`

```js
const hugeData = [{ name: "store 1", code: "code 1",available: false}, { name: "store 2", code: "simple_code",available: true}, { name: "sto 3", code: "has no cde", available: true }]

const filters = { code: "ode", name: "re" }

let final = hugeData.filter(value => {
  return Object.entries(value).some(([key, value]) => {
    return typeof value == 'string' && value.includes(filters[key])
  })
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be faster - storing the `Object.keys()` result, and filtering out any keys that aren't on the first store (assuming all stores are equivalent). I also used a single object for `filters`.

```js
const hugeData = [
  { name: "store 1", code: "code 1", available: false },
  { name: "store 2", code: "simple_code", available: true },
  { name: "sto 3", code: "has no cde", available: true }
];

const filters = { code: "ode", name: "re" };
const keys = Object.keys(filters).filter(k => hugeData[0].hasOwnProperty(k));

console.log(
  hugeData.filter(s => keys.some(k => s[k].includes(filters[k])))
);
```

If you wanted ALL filters, to match, you could change it to `every`:

```
hugeData.filter(s => keys.every(k => s[k].includes(filters[k])))
```