# Dynamically Filtering an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a requirement very similar to [How to filter array by array of dynamic objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58576311/how-to-filter-array-by-array-of-dynamic-objects) however I need to filter on all values in my filter object.  Please see my test below

```js
let cardsArray = [
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Contenders","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2011"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Contenders","status":"Own","userName":"jinky32","year":"2011"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"dfgdf","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Contenders","status":"Own","userName":"gdgg","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2010"}
]
//const filters = {userName:"tyty",status:"Own",year:"2011",series:"Contenders"}
//const filters = {series:"Contenders",year:"2011"};
const filters = {series:"Contenders"};


let final = cardsArray.filter(value => {
  return Object.entries(value).some(([key, value]) => {
    return typeof value == 'string' && value.includes(filters[key])
  })
})

console.log(final)
```

If my filter object contains one pair e.g. `const filters = {series:"Contenders"};` then it works.  However I need to filter based on more than one pair e.g. `const filters = {series:"Contenders",year:"2011"};` (and ultimately more), however when I do this the second pair is not taken into account.

Can anyone advise on the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition should be that all `filters`'s `key-value` pairs are satisfied in a `card` element:

```js
let cardsArray = [
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Contenders","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2011"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Contenders","status":"Own","userName":"jinky32","year":"2011"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"dfgdf","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Contenders","status":"Own","userName":"gdgg","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2010"},
   {"brand":"National Treasures","manufacturer":"Panini","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","userName":"tyty","year":"2010"}
]
const filters = {series:"Contenders",year:"2011"};


let final = cardsArray.filter(card => 
  Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => card[key]===value)
);

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
let final = cardsArray.filter(obj => {
    return ! Object
        .keys(filters)
        .map(key => obj[key] === filters[key])
        .includes(false)
})
```